# Can we send an email to a campaign containing both contacts and leads

Tags: marketing-cloud, campaign

I have few questions.

1. When SFMC is linked to a Salesforce campaign, should both Leads and Contacts be included in the SFMC distribution list?
2. Can a column be added to the view so that users can easily see how many campaign members have been added to the SFMC audience, as well as a breakdown of Leads vs Contacts?
3. Can we send an email to a campaign containing both contacts and leads

Comment: can you elaborate on what you need in terms of campaign members vs. SFMC audience? They would normally be the same within 15 minutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) To my knowledge, you could include both - shouldn't make a difference. It's only in Journey's that there is a distinction between Leads and Contacts

2) Depending on which view you are talking about (i'm assuming you're in SF Core), you can create two roll-up summaries that counts whether it is a lead or a contact. Note: You would need to add a workflow + field update that checks whether it is a lead or contact that is added as a campaign memember.

3) Yes you can - guided sends, content builder sends and journeys based on campaign members can handle both.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes , more information you can refer this link 
   https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=faq_campaigns_how_can_i_add_contacts.htm&type=0

3.Yes, contact and leads are quite different, refer this link https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000DPXHAA4

Using guided send you can send emails to both contact and leads.